# After deploy rails on Heroku Does`t work js and css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After deploy on heroku does not work js (jquery). But on locale  machine all well.

I have file (push_notification.js) with js in javascripts directory.

```
$((function(){
  $("#dv").attr('class', 'animated fadeInDown delay-0s')
  setTimeout(function () {
      $("#dv").attr('class', 'hidden')
  }, 6000)
}));
```

On heroku it does not work.

My application.js

```
//= require_self
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require rails-ujs

//= require push_notification
//= require admin_panel
//= require_tree .
```

Pls prompt me, solution this problem

Comment: try assets precompile on heroku

Comment: I tried to run, but nothing changed

Comment: check any error in the console log. and try restarting your server

Comment: There are no problems, neither in the heroku logs nor in the browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can use the asset pipeline on Heroku.

1. Compiling assets locally.
2. Compiling assets during slug compilation.

To compile your assets locally, run the assets:precompile task locally on your app. Make sure to use the production environment so that the production version of your assets are generated.

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

A public/assets directory will be created

```
git add public/assets
git commit -m "vendor compiled assets"
```

For more ref use this link [enter link description here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline)

Comment: TY but i use like: `"heroku run RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile"` and it worked